# Backbone Model.parse called but has not effect

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, coffeescript

I've got a model that looks like this (in coffeescript):

```
class MyModel extends Backbone.Model
    parse: (response) ->
        console.log 'Parse triggered!'
        return response.response

    myFunction: (data, callback) ->
        self = this
        this.fetch
            data: data
            processData: true
            success: (model, response) ->
                console.log response
                # App specific stuff happens here
            error: (model, response) -> console.log response
```

The JSON response from the server is formatted like this:

```
{
    response: {
        id: 1,
        foo: 'blah'
        bar: 'meh'
    }
}
```

As far as I understand the console.log in myFunction should simply contain the value of `response` from the JSON. What appears to be happening, however, is that I see the log `Parse triggered!`, but the response object that I'm accessing in myFunction is not parsed at all. In other words, its as if the JSON had just been passed straight through.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is response inside of the success handler coming back as an object or a string?

Comment: Response is coming back as an object.

Comment: Also, if it's coming back as the full object {response:{...}}, this would be expected. Parse's job is only to handle the response so that the model's attributes can be updated automatically.

Comment: Yep I was wrongly thinking that parse() was used as a sort of response pre-processor rather than to get the model from the response.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`Model#fetch`](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-fetch) will call the success handler *after* populating the model, [`parse`](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-parse) will be called *before* populating the model. If you look at `model` inside your success callback you should see the `id`, `foo`, and `bar` values from your JSON. The `response` passed to the success callback will be the raw AJAX response object.

Comment: Thanks! I was confusing the role of the model and response args in the callback.